# PHP multidimensional array to json echoes only the first result

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, multidimensional-array

i am writing an API for an online service I am developing, the code below should get the data from the db and structure it somewhat like this:

```
{
    data: [
            {
                    name: [
                            "xxx"
                    ],
                    description: [
                            "xxx"
                    ],
                    event_date: [
                            "xxx"
                    ],
            }
            {
                    name: [
                            "yyy"
                    ],
                    description: [
                            "yyy"
                    ],
                    event_date: [
                            "yyy"
                    ],
            }
    ]
 }
```

but instead, it is showing up like this:

```
{
    data: [
            {
                    name: [
                            "xxx"
                    ],
                    description: [
                            "xxx"
                    ],
                    event_date: [
                            "xxx"
                    ],
            }
    ]
 }
```

i have no idea what i'm doing wrong, surely it has to be something stupid simple...

here's the code:

```
if($result) {

  $i = 0;
  $x = 0;

  $results_main_array['data'] = array();
  $description_array = array("name", "description", "event_date", "location", "photos", "logo", "video");
  $results_array = array();

  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    foreach($row as $r) {

      if($i >= count($row)) {
        $i = 0;

        array_push($results_main_array['data'], $results_array);
      }

      $results_array[$description_array[$i]] = array($r);

      ++$i;
    }
  }

  echo json_encode($results_main_array);
} else {

  echo "else";
}
```

Comment: why you reset  `$results_array = array();` in if condition

Comment: ups, sorry, that was just a trial i did

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry to waste anyone's time, i found what was wrong, i had

```
array_push($results_main_array['data'], $results_array);
```

inside the foreach, once i put it out of that loop everything goes fine.